# How to display a modal Window in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin7

I'm new to Vaadin and am still learning. Here I am trying to get a basic Vaadin project to compile. I want it to and display a modal window when the UI runs, but am having trouble. Here is what I have so far:

CaptchaUI.java -

```
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;


public abstract class CaptchaUI extends UI {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        addWindow(new CaptchaWindow());

    }
}
```

CaptchaWindow.java -

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;


public class CaptchaWindow extends Window {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CaptchaWindow() {

    // Some other UI content
    setContent(new Label("Here's my UI"));

    // Create a sub-window and set the content
    Window subWindow = new Window("Sub Window");
    VerticalLayout subContent = new VerticalLayout();
    subContent.setMargin(true);
    subWindow.setContent(subContent);

    // Put some components in it
    subContent.addComponent(new Label("Label"));
    subContent.addComponent(new Button("Button"));

    // Center it in the browser window
    subWindow.center();

    // Open it in the UI
    addWindow(subWindow);

    }
}
```

Could someone give me some help or recommendation to get it to display?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What are your research efforts so far? Did you google "vaadin modal window"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-sub-window.html#layout.sub-window.modal) it is just as easy as setting

```
setModal(true)
```

on the sub window to make it modal.

Please note that the modal feature of Vaadin is just a client side restriction. Modifying the HTML with debug tools in the browser could still make it possible to click buttons in the background.